# ZF2 unit testing without DB and view

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Following the Zend [guide to unit testing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/tutorials/unittesting.html), the section *A failing test case* doesn't work as described. A database connection is indeed established.

If I unset the config var config_glob_paths in the setUp() function, it will then fail as originally excepted.

Then the view models are run. If using the albumTable mock, fetchAll() returns an array() instead of a Pagination object as the view expects.

> Argument 1 passed to Zend\View\Helper\PaginationControl::__invoke() must be an instance of Zend\Paginator\Paginator, array given

I'm guessing the docs are outdated. Surely the DB connection and especially execution of the view should not occur.

How can I run tests without these two things automatically happening?

Comment: Please add some code to give more info.

Comment: You will need to utilize mocking. http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/test-doubles.html